# LayoutParams of custom ViewGroup don't show up in Android Studio editor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a class that extends `LinearLayout` - it's almost identical, it just measures slightly differently.

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    <Standard constructors...>

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        <Custom measuring code here>
    }
}
```

That works all great, but now none of the children show ANY of the LinearLayout's LayoutParams attributes in the layout editor's properties in Android Studio, even something like `layout:width`.

My guess is that LayoutParams are not inherited, so I just duplicated `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` and added it everywhere, i.e.:

```
public class CustomLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    public static class LayoutParams extends LinearLayout.LayoutParams {

        public LayoutParams(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(c, attrs);
        }

        public LayoutParams(int width, int height) {
            super(width, height);
        }

        public LayoutParams(int width, int height, float weight) {
            super(width, height, weight);
        }

        public LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
            super(p);
        }

        public LayoutParams(MarginLayoutParams source) {
            super(source);
        }

        public LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams source) {
            super(source);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs) {
        return new LayoutParams(getContext(), attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
        return new LayoutParams(p);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean checkLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
        return p instanceof LayoutParams;
    }
```

And, in attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="com.domain.package.CustomLinearLayout_Layout">
    <attr name="layout_width" format="dimension">
        <enum name="fill_parent" value="-1" />
        <enum name="match_parent" value="-1" />
        <enum name="wrap_content" value="-2" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

Here is the view in the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.domain.package.CustomLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Mostly as a test to see if that works. Still, nothing shows up in the editor. I did compile the project, and tried the `declare-styleable` with and without the full package name. What am I missing?

(EDIT: Just to clarify the ultimate goal - I want `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`' attributes visible in the Android Studio editor. I had been hoping that they're inherited automatically, but since that's not the case, I'm trying to duplicate them by subclassing `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, but that doesn't work either. If there's a way to just inherit `LinearLayout`'s styleables, that would be preferred.)

Comment: Have you added the `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/[your package name]` xml namespace to your layout?

Comment: @Mike Yes, I have. Using res-auto. It even seems to understand it, I see suggestions in auto-complete when I edit the layout XML file, but it still won't show up in the layout editor.

Comment: didn't test it but what about if you place a tag <LinearLayout> with an antribute class="your.class.here"? note: its class,  not android:class

Comment: @pskink I'm using `com.domain.package.CustomLinearLayout` - I edited the question to add the pertinent part of the layout. What does your syntax mean? Does it actually create an instance of type `your.class.here`? What is the purpose of `LinearLayout` as far as the runtime goes?

Comment: @EboMike i tested ny proposal and the editor works fine but in order to make your.class.here to be crested at runtime you would need to implement LayoutInflater.Factory,  the question is: does it pay off?